# Difference between Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore and Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

Love to understand the difference between these two :

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore

And
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

Aspnecore.identity comes default with .net(6)(it's namespace exist in my .net6 app though Microsoft said it's legacy )
But Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore has to be installed as a budget package

I couldn't find anything on Microsoft documentation about Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity provides the core system for identity management, but can be used with any data storage solution.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#identity-components):

> The primary package for Identity is Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.
> This package contains the core set of interfaces for ASP.NET Core
> Identity, and is included by
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.